# What would happen if an LED was run in a 500F/260C environment?

Tags: led

I'm trying to get a better understanding of what the heat would do to the LED. I understand that LEDs and heat do not get along, but if they were put in this high heat, what would happen?

Would they still function?
Would it just be their life and/or output that would diminish?

Thanks in advance for any info you can provide.

Dave.

Comment: The plastic would melt or burn for one. The LED chip would probably be next.

Comment: Reflow soldering profiles (check datasheet or manufacturer website) usually specify around 260C for a very brief duration, during which time the solder melts. If held for too long duration, internal connections could possibly be damaged.

Comment: @MarkU very good point on the reflow. Didn't think of that. The parts must be able to survive some length of time like you mentioned. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we assume the materials in use can all survive in excess of 260C.

If we assume the device is increased in temperature at such a rate that difference in thermal expansion of the associated materials (wafer, substrate, electrical connection...) can be ignored & thus the device will not rip itself apart during the temperature increase.

IF we assuming the device is still operated within its power capability at these elevated temperatures.

Leaving purely the physics of semiconductors to ponder:

One of the most obvious affected characteristics is the bandgap of the semiconductor material.

\$E_g(T) = E_g(0) - \frac{\alpha T^2}{T + \beta} \$

\begin{array} {|r|r|}
\hline
Material & E_g(0) (eV) & \alpha_E (eV/K) & \beta_E (K) \\
\hline
GaAs & 1.519 & 5.41*10^{-4} & 204 \\
\hline
Si & 1.170 & 4.73*10^{-4} & 636 \\
\hline
Ge & 0.7437 & 4.77*10^{-4} & 235 \\
\hline
\end{array}

With increased temperature, there is a decrease in bandgap energy. At 260C, for Si, the bandgap energy has decreased to  1.055eV (from 1.17 at -273C, from 1.12 at 22C). Less and less energy is required for an electron to become "excited"

What does this mean?  With increased temperature, the ability for the doped silicon to behave as a semiconductor diminishes... its characteristics tend towards the intrinsic behavior of the undoped material at the equivalent temperature - conductive.

This equally means the ability for an LED to operate as an LED is diminished.

At 260C a Si P-N junction will still exhibit semiconductive properties

The Carrier density (decreases) , mobility (decreases) & diffusion (increases) equally are affected by temperatures which all result in a reduced current density capability.

[Cissoid](http://www.cissoid.com/) are a manufacturer of high temperature **PACKAGED** semiconductor devices (+225C ambient)

Equally [Honeywell](http://www51.honeywell.com/aero/common/documents/myaerospacecatalog-documents/Missiles-Munitions/High_Temperature_Products_Brochure.pdf) offer a limited product range that will operate up to +300C

BOTH put caveats on the life expectancy ( 5years at 300+ )

http://www.extremetemperatureelectronics.com/tutorial3.html

http://www.springer.com/cda/content/document/cda_downloaddocument/9781461407478-c1.pdf?SGWID=0-0-45-1268751-p174130080

Comment: very helpful response! Some of that calculations are beyond my understanding, but the info is very good. Especially the link to the extremetemperatureelectronics.com. Definitely points me in the right direction. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Packaging of most LEDs would degrade very quickly- epoxy breaks down at high temperatures, and I imagine the soft material used in some white LEDs (silicone?) would also degrade.

Certain LEDs are made to withstand high temperatures and would probably last quite a while at that temperature (hours, perhaps) before degrading too much if the self-heating is kept to a minimum or they are not powered. I'm talking about expensive hermetic LEDs with glass or quartz windows, not your garden-variety cheap LED.

The 260°C temperature may be briefly seen during IR reflow soldering of normal LEDs but the exposure is measured in seconds.

Speaking of which, you'd have to figure out how to attach to the leads (welding, perhaps) since ordinary solder would be molten.

In operation, the wavelength emitted by the LED would increase substantially.. blue would tend towards green or yellow, and red would slip towards infrared, and there would be a commensurate decrease in forward voltage at a given current.

Comment: Thanks @Spehro very helpful info, especially the colour change comment.